# dpkg opporations fail: Failed to run depmod, error processing linux-image-generic

Tags: 13.10, apt, kernel, dpkg

My Laptop had lost power a couple of times recently, and now, whenever I try to do a package operation I am getting the following error code. I tried searching for a solution on the forums, but these either required a package operation or were left unanswered. 'uname -r' tells me my kernel is 3.11.0-17-generic, but it seems like my kernel header says 3.11.0-18-generic. I tried booting old kernel versions to try to fix the issue, but I encountered the same error. Anyone know what I could do?

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic (3.11.0-18.32) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to run depmod
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic:
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.11.0.18.19); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: post the output of `uname -r` command.

Comment: as stated in the question,  it is '3.11.0-17-generic'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands to remove unconfigured  packages,

```
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-generic
sudo dpkg -P linux-generic
```

Then finally run the below command to fix the package dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: As stated in the question, every time I try to do a package operation, I get this error code, and this method, requiring a package operation, fails for me.

Comment: Post the output of first command on pastebin

Comment: Many apologies and thanks. I did not have access to my laptop at the time of my reply, and assumed, based on the fact that both 'dpkg --configure' and 'apt-get purge' yielded the same result, that this would end up the same. Stupid assumption for sure. Thanks