# "Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet." Error

Tags: 14.04, grub2, apt, upgrade, dpkg

When I try to upgrade via terminal using `sudo apt-get upgrade` this error appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic (3.13.0-37.64) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.13.0-37.64 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.13.0-37.64 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 3.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic...
P: Installing debian theme...cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-wheezy/extlinux/memtest.bin’: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.37.44); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux:
 linux depends on linux-generic; however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To solve the problem I tried

- [I get this error after upgade. please help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360023/i-get-this-error-after-upgade-please-help)
- [Accidentally deleted the "linux-image-generic"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42883/accidentally-deleted-the-linux-image-generic)
- [Unmet dependencies when trying to update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429731/unmet-dependencies-when-trying-to-update)
- [dpkg opporations fail: Failed to run depmod, error processing linux-image-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435571/dpkg-opporations-fail-failed-to-run-depmod-error-processing-linux-image-generi)
- [libpam systemd - installation error ubuntu 14.04 unable to install updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469474/libpam-systemd-installation-error-ubuntu-14-04-unable-to-install-updates)
- ["apt-get -f install" fails with "/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187958/apt-get-f-install-fails-with-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)
- [Fixing software center catalog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30993/fixing-software-center-catalog)
- [dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517857/dpkg-error-processing-package-linux-image-generic-configure-dependency-pro)

This is my [/etc/grub.d/00_header](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8552173/) content.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get purge extlinux` yet?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by:

```
apt-get install memtest86+
```